# Will HP Pavillion G6 laptop's processor (core i5 3210M) work in other motherboards?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hp-pavilion, intel-core-i5

I have a HP laptop (Pavillion g6). Its motherboard has some issue which is not repairable.  A new motherboard is too costly.

Can I create a new system using other motherboards like gigabyte or MSI mini-ITX motherboards?

Comment: Laptop processors are different than desktop processors, be sure you pick a motherboard with the correct cpu socket for that processor. The socket needed for that processor is FCPGA988. More socket information here...http://superuser.com/questions/591345/what-do-intels-socket-package-specifications-mean-in-detail

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possibly.

Laptop processors are different than desktop processors, be sure you pick a motherboard with the correct cpu socket for that processor. The socket needed for that processor is [FCPGA988 aka G2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G2)

[More information on sockets here](http://Laptop%20processors%20are%20different%20than%20desktop%20processors,%20be%20sure%20you%20pick%20a%20motherboard%20with%20the%20correct%20cpu%20socket%20for%20that%20processor.%20The%20socket%20needed%20for%20that%20processor%20is%20FCPGA988.%20More%20socket%20information%20here)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes there are motherboards available with socket G2, but I was not sure about processor compatibility with the motherboard and bios and any other factor.

Comment: I see no reason for compatibility issues when the motherboard supports that socket type.